# how to login into a iOS homescreen bookmarked webapp using a passwordless magic link: universal link?

Tags: javascript, cookies, ios-universal-links, password-less

I've a webapp (= website available at `https://www.example.com`) which uses passwordless login through a magic link.

This very same webapp can be install on iOS using `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` meta tag (= bookmark my webapp on the iOS homescreen and open without Safari chrome/address bar...).

However, I'm not able to login to my webapp from this chromeless Safari, because when I click on my magic link in my email, It opens Safari and set my cookie in Safari - cookie that is not shared with my chromeless safari.

Is there a way to solve this?
Universal link seems to be for native app, not website/webapp.

Thanks